# Cannot I declare an attribute with type in zope.interface?

Tags: python, zope.interface

I'm using `zope.interface` module to declare an interface with some methods and attributes. Also, cannot I somehow declare not only the attribute names, but also their **types?**

```
from zope.interface import Interface, Attribute, implementer, verify

class IVehicle(Interface):
    """Any moving thing"""
    speed = Attribute("""Movement speed""") #CANNOT I DECLARE ITS TYPE HERE?
    def move():
        """Make a single step"""
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the type of the attribute by introducing an `invariant`.

```
from zope.interface import Interface, Attribute, implementer, verify, invariant

def speed_invariant(ob):
    if not isinstance(ob.speed, int):
       raise TypeError("speed must be an int")

class IVehicle(Interface):
    """Any moving thing"""
    speed = Attribute("""Movement speed""")
    invariant(speed_invariant)

    def move():
        """Make a single step"""
        pass
```

your `IVehicle` class has a `validateInvariants` method you can call to validate none of the invariants are being broken in classes that implement it.

```
IVehicle.validateInvariants(vechile_instance)
```

I don't know of a way to specify the type of the Attribute directly, though.